# Function printing strange values. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, alignment

Consider this example:

```
class A
{
public:
     int a;
public:
     A():a(1){};
};

class B:public A
{
public:
     int b;
public:
     B():b(2){};
};

void print(A* a)
{
     for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
     {
          cout<<a[i].a<<" ";
     } 
}

int main()
{
     B b[10];
     print(b);
}
```

My program output is : `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2.`
But how it is accessing data b through a[i].a, because I never mentioned b in the output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `sizeof(A) != sizeof(B)`.

And the `print` function thinks that is has an array (essentially) of `A` objects. It doesn't know anything about `B` or its members.

While `B` is an `A`, `B[]` is *not* an `A[]`.

---

There are three natural ways to solve your problem:

1. Make `print` take a `B*` argument.
2. Make `print` a template function.
3. Create an overload of `print` that takes a `B*` argument.

Which one to pick is up to you, and depends on your use-case.

---

*Why* you seem to print values from `B` is because of the memory layout.

An array of `A` look something like this in memory:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| A[0].a | A[1].a | A[2].a | A[3].a | A[4].a | A[5].a | A[6].a | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

An array of `B` look like this

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| B[0].a | B[0].b | B[1].a | B[1].b | B[2].a | B[2].b | B[3].a | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

Now if we put the two arrays next to each other:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| A[0].a | A[1].a | A[2].a | A[3].a | A[4].a | A[5].a | A[6].a | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
| B[0].a | B[0].b | B[1].a | B[1].b | B[2].a | B[2].b | B[3].a | ... |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-----+
```

With the above "overlay" it's easy to see why you seem to be printing the `b` member from the `B` class.

Comment: Should it not invoke a warning at least? It seems to be quite undesirable and possibly UB. Also, what would happen if B class had a `float` member rather than `int`? Implicit `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: I understand the alignment problem. I am just curious why a[i].a printing b. Because hence the second part of object B b itself. I mean  why isn't this a compile error.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan It's not an error because you pass a *pointer* to `A`. An array of `B` object is not the same as an array of `A` object, but a pointer to `B` and a pointer to `A` are compatible, otherwise polymorphism wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot rely on this behavior, a probable explanation for the output,

Considering an array of objects of `B`

```
   a|b   |  a|b    
 object1   object2
```

When you interpret it as `A*`

```
     a     |    b    |   a 
  object1    object2   object3
```

Hence you get `1 2 1 2..`.